# Wordpress DB query too slow

Tags: mysql, wordpress, performance, query-performance

since last wednesday I'm having massive performance issues on my website because of MySQL queries...

In DB I have 20.000 posts and about 180.000 meta rows.

Query like:

```
SELECT t.*, tt.*, tr.object_id
FROM az2_terms AS t 
INNER JOIN az2_term_taxonomy AS tt
ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
INNER JOIN az2_term_relationships AS tr
ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('znacka', 'model')
AND tr.object_id IN (27130, 27290, 27822, 27899, 30862, 33536, 33721, 34901, 37448, 37482, 37496, 37522, 37572, 37580, 37742, 37750, 38160, 38165)
ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

Takes almost 20 seconds to finish and it makes the website totally unusable.
I've disabled all WP plugins, changed theme, but nothing helped.

I've tried profiling in MyAdmin and the first run takes almost 20s, the second run is almost instant.

Any ideas?

Comment: You forgot to put `*` after `t.`and `tt.` (or desired columns, if you do not want to get all table columns). Also make sure you have indexes **on right places** in your tables `az2termtaxonomy` and `az2termrelationships`

Comment: I'm sorry, it's alredy stripped from those chars since my ISP does that. The query itself works well, but takes so long

Comment: You have lots of posts and post_meta information. But this query relates not to posts but to this aztaxonomy subsystem.  Please look at this, paying special attention to the section on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Please [edit] your question to provide more details?  If this is from a plugin, you may get better luck from your plugin vendor than you will from us.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the 3 tables.  It could be a simple matter of fixing the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try.

First, your *"driving"* table is `az2_term_taxonomy` based on your `WHERE` clause. Try re-writing with that:

```
SELECT t.*, tt.*, tr.object_id
FROM az2_term_taxonomy AS tt
INNER JOIN az2_term_relationships AS tr
ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN az2_terms AS t  
ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('znacka', 'model')
AND tr.object_id IN (27130, 27290, 27822, 27899, 30862, 33536, 33721, 34901, 37448, 37482, 37496, 37522, 37572, 37580, 37742, 37750, 38160, 38165)
ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

Second, `tr.object_id` lookup with `IN ()` is usually very slow. **If** you can, create an indexed temp table and move those ids into the table and do a LEFT JOIN ON it. let me know if you want the syntax

Comment: The order of tables in a `INNER JOIN` is irrelevant.  The Optimizer will (effectively) reorder them to discover the 'best' table to start with.

Comment: @RickJames - I can't respond to what is *supposed* to happen. But I've had a few cases where it made a difference, the optimizer got it wrong and switching the order (basically hinting the best table to drive the JOINs) sped things up.

Comment: OK, that's feasible.  But I suspect it was coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solutions... well - at least the problem.

When I was switching to HTTPS, some error occured during the import of the edited .sql file (duplicate index, I think)
But everything seemed to work allright, so I didn't pay much attention to it.

But it seems, like the import was the problem. I deleted the database and imported the backup - violá, everything is fine now.

The moral is - Pay atention to error messages.